# Crystal Reports- Change a parameter value for every details view

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, detailsview

I am working on a Crystal Reports document which I require changing a parameter that will be produced from the code-behind. I already know how to set the parameter's value through the code, however I need it to work dynamically in the details view.

Because the details view can occur many times, I would like to know if it is **possible to programmatically set a different value to the parameter every time the details view runs?** I know it would be better to get the value from a dataset, which is what I am already doing, but for this value it needs to be entered through a parameter simply because it does not exist in our sql databases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the SQL used in your report? I find it difficult to visualise what you want to do.

Comment: My SQL is really large. It doesnt really need to be seen to understand the question and I dont really know how to explain it better. Basically, I want to change the parameter everytime through code to a different value for each instance of the detailsview.

Comment: More info about the data structure and what you're trying to accomplish, please. You may be able to do it another, more straight-forward way.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Set datasource first
         myDataReport.SetDataSource(...)

         myDataReport.SetParameterValue("MyParameter", "Hello");
         */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.